# How do I unlock the "All Skills Learned" trophy after hitting Level 50?

Tags: achievements, horizon-zero-dawn

I'm level 50, but I only have 2 points to spend and 2 abilities left to unlock. Side quests only give XP so what now? Level 50 is the max level so XP from quests do nothing. In fact, I think I've completed all quests now. How am I supposed to unlock the other skills if I can't get any more Skill Points from leveling up?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The main quests as well as the Hunter Trials will award you Skill Points. If I remember correctly, main quests usually give you a Skill Point as a reward. Getting Blazing Suns on all 3 Hunter Trials at a Hunter Trial area will also award you a Skill Point. Additionally, completing Cauldrons and climbing Tallnecks will reward you Skill Points. If you haven't done all of these, you definitely should. From experience, I capped out my Skills by the mid-40s and was still receiving Skill Points from main quests and level ups, despite having nothing to spend them on.

By the end of the game, completing Hunter Trials and Main Quests should award you way more than the required number of Skill Points required to unlock all skills.

Comment: Ahh ok thank's yes I haven't done the hunter trials yet so how many point's will I gain there? I need 4 more points. Thanks!

Comment: @Kev Each Hunter Trial area will give you one for getting blazing suns for all three trials at the locations. There are 5 Hunter Trial locationa (15 Trials total), so you'll get 5 Skill Points from those.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I'd messed up this trophy, time to hit the trials...

Comment: @Kev fun fact, there are no missable trophies in this game

Comment: I actualy thought it was a bug with the game haha

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to receive skill points. Tallnecks, cauldrons, hunting trials, and main story quests all give skill points as well.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting all the metal flowers, vantage points, vessels  and banuk figures each gives tons of skill points! At the time I found the last metal flower I had 5 Skill Points saved up. It jumped to 11 when I earned the flower trophy! They also jumped when I got the last ancient vessel, etc. Easiest way is to buy the maps locating the collectibles and bounce around campfire to campfire with Golden Fast Pack until you've got them all. I'm only at level 43 and I only have one skill left to unlock.